# Refresh controller when factory data updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a Factory:

```
function PeriodDataService (APIService) {

    var periodData = {}

    periodData.refresh = function(user) {
        APIService.query({ route:'period', id: user._id }, function(data) {
            periodData.orders = data[0].orders
        })
    }
    periodData.orders = []
    periodData.preiod = 1

    return periodData


}
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('PeriodDataService', PeriodDataService)
```

And some controllers...for example this one, which use the factory data

```
function ProductionCtrl ($scope, PeriodDataService) {

    $scope.board = PeriodDataService.board
    $scope.period = PeriodDataService.period
}
angular
    .module('loop')
    .controller('ProductionCtrl', ProductionCtrl)
```

When I call the refresh, the Controlles dont update there data. Whats the reason?

```
PeriodDataService.refresh(user)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this your complete code example? Where `user` came from? You have syntax error too.

Comment: The User is set in the MainCtrl where PeriodDataService.refresh(user) ist called. The APIService works, periodData.orders = data[0].orders writes the new data in orders. But the data isnt refreshed in ProductionCtrl. I need a watch?

Comment: You need to return the promise from the refresh function so that your controller can use the .when() callback function and re-assign the new data.

Comment: Do you have a example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you call `refresh` and your service does

```
periodData.orders = data[0].orders
```

your service is changing the `periodData.orders` property to point to a different array than the one it was set to point to when you initialized it (via `periodData.orders = []`).

This breaks the connection between your controller and the data array in your service because your controller was set up to point to the original array when you did

```
$scope.orders = PeriodDataService.orders
```

(which I don't actually see in your sample code but which I assume you're doing somewhere).

This simply set `$scope.orders` equal to the same pointer as `periodData.orders`, thus pointing to the original array in memory, and allowing the controller to see changes to that array.

When your service changes `periodData.orders` to a different pointer, nothing changes the pointer value of `$scope.orders`, so it's still pointing to the original array, which hasn't changed.

There are different ways you can fix this.

#### Approach 1

You could have your service `.push()` the new data into `periodData.orders` rather than set `periodData.orders` equal to the returned data array. So your `refresh` method would look like this:

```
periodData.refresh = function(user) {
    APIService.query({ route:'period', id: user._id }, function(data) {
        periodData.orders.length = 0; // empty current orders array

        // push the returned orders data into orders array
        data[0].orders.forEach(function (item, index) {
            periodData.orders.push(item);
        });
    });
};
```

As long as you just add to or remove from the original array, and don't redefine it (don't ever do another `periodData.orders =`), it should work fine.

#### Approach 2

Alternatively, you could create a new object to hold the `orders` array (and any other data elements you want to expose) and have a `$scope` property pointing to that object rather than to the array itself.

So your service would look like this:

```
function PeriodDataService (APIService) {
    var periodDataSvc = {};

    // create data object to hold service data
    periodDataSvc.periodData = {
        orders: [],
        period: 1
    };

    periodDataSvc.refresh = function(user) {
        APIService.query({ route:'period', id: user._id }, function(data) {
            periodDataSvc.periodData.orders = data[0].orders
        })
    }

    return periodDataSvc;
}
```

with the `orders` array now one level deeper at `periodDataSvc.periodData.orders`.

And you would have a `$scope` property pointing to the `periodData` object rather than to the `orders` array:

```
function ProductionCtrl($scope, PeriodDataService) {
    $scope.periodData = PeriodDataService.periodData;
}
```

So in your service, when you set the `orders` array equal to the returned array from your APIService, the controller will see that change because it's watching the `periodData` object, and a property on that object has changed.

And of course, since you changed the `$scope` property, any markup that was referencing the `orders` array would also then need to change to reference `periodData.orders` instead. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in periodData.orders">{{order.id}}: {{order.item}}</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r5s2fnq/2/) showing both approaches.

Comment: why I cant do periodDataSvc.periodData = data[0] in the refresh? And why $scope.orders = PeriodDataService.periodData.orders not working in the controller?

Comment: It's the same issue you had originally: you're initializing your controller to watch a particular object in memory, then when you get your data back, your service isn't updating that object, it's redefining `periodDataSvc.periodData` to point to a different object.

Comment: For example, let's say `periodDataSvc.periodData` gets initialized to a value of `0x123` (since it's just a pointer to an object in memory). Then in your controller, `$scope.periodData = PeriodDataService.periodData` sets `$scope.periodData` equal to `0x123` also, pointing to that same object, and able to see changes to that object. If your service then does `periodDataSvc.periodData = data[0]`, it sets `periodDataSvc.periodData` equal to whatever `data[0]`'s pointer value is, say, `0x456`. But your controller is watching for changes to the object at `0x123`, so it doesn't see anything change.

Comment: But if your service does `periodDataSvc.periodData.orders = data[0].orders`, it's changing the `orders` property of the object at `0x123`, so the controller will see that change.

Answer (score 0):

I used **$rootScope** in the factory and **$scope.$on** in the controller to solve this.
When I change the factory, i use **$rootScope.$broadcast** to tell the controller that I change it.

```
.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var dataFactory = {
        stock: null,
        getStock: getStock
    }

    function getStock() {
        $http.get("/api/itemfarmacia/").then(function success(res) {
            dataFactory.stock = res.data;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataFactory.stock');
        }, function error(err) {
            onsole.log("Bad request");
        })
    }

    return dataFactory;
}])
```

and in the controller

```
.controller('atencion', ["$scope", "$state", "dataFactory", function ($scope, $state, dataFactory) {
    $scope.stock = dataFactory.stock;
    dataFactory.getStock(); //wherever you execute this, $scope.stock will change

    $scope.$on('dataFactory.stock', function () {
        $scope.stock = dataFactory.stock; //Updating $scope
    })
}])
```